# How to create a batch file that auto SSH into a local server and launches a python script in the terminal?

Tags: windows, batch-file, linux-mint

I have a batch file that performs a login into the SSH server. But I want to launch an app into the terminal for me to view its results, eg HTOP or TMUX.

Basically to run a command after login. It performs the login but doesn't run the next command.

What am I doing wrong?

Contents of my batch file :

`@ECHO OFF`
`start cmd.exe /K "ssh user@address && htop"`

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
@echo off

ssh user@address

Start "x:\Directory\Which\The\HTOP\Is\Located\htop.exe"
```

This code will do the trick ^

What you were doing wrong is, that you were not specifying the directory that the `htop` is in. You should specify that directory, and then run the `htop`

(replace this with the folder that you have HTOP).

PS: You dont call `cmd.exe` in a batch file, coz the Batch file is run in the CMD environment.

Comment: I tried your code, it logs me into the ssh server like mine does. but doesnt start the next app, even after i write down the full path.
PS: htop is basically an command in linux that launches the HTOP app. it doesn't need a path.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of the screen that pops up after you run your batch file? just to check whats wrong. if it gives a error code or something?